# What can I do with a PMML document?

Tags: r, statistics, sas, data-mining, pmml

Basic question: I know that models created in R and SAS can be saved as PMML.  But what is the next step?

For example, are there Java and Python libraries that automatically execute regressions stored as PMML, where you just pass in a PMML file for parsing and the library does the rest?  Or is PMML just a standard that usually results in an engineer still having to translate the code from scratch?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language

Comment: That link doesn't answer my question, and it's one of the sources I checked before asking it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously there are Java and Python packages that extract PMML files and return the evaluation.

- In Java, see JPmml: https://github.com/jpmml
- In Python, see Augustus: https://code.google.com/p/augustus/